# Responsive CSS inline text (with different font-size)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, header, sass

I am trying to create a header with a subheader. Simple that is, there are few things I would like to implement:

1. The text should be inline with each other, with about 20px space. (When using bootstrap they tend to float away from each other)
2. When the text is bigger than the window, it should break into two separate rows by heading and subheading respectively.

I would love if it looked anything like this (but just text) - the main landing page. I am so curious how he did it :P

http://underscoredesign.com/

Tried using bootstrap:

```
  <div class="page1">
        <div class="container-fluid middlepage">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                      <h1>ABCDEF<h1>
                </div>
                 <div class="col-md-4">
                      <h5>ghjklmnopqrstuv</h5>
                 </div>
            </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: the reason you're getting the downvotes is because on this site you'll have to show us what you tried, and let us know where you got stuck then we'll be keen to help you troubleshoot...

Comment: [How to ask?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

**updated answer

First off, read this step-by-step and I think you'll get a better understanding: http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Second, you probably don't need that extra div wrapped around your container (.page1). You may be able to add that to your container div. Not sure what you're trying to do with .middlepage class. Center? You can do that with bootstrap classes, so you don't have to create new CSS classes.

Third, you haven't created any rows. Bootstrap is a table-like grid system. You have rows and columns. Please read ALL of this: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/

Fourth, Bootstrap works as a 12-column grid system. Your large column that contains the two smaller columns only adds up to 10.

Good luck!

---

Since we don't know what you've tried (as the other commenters stated), here are some stabs in the dark:

1. Try aligning your items left
2. Try margin/padding styles
3. If you want the columns to switch from 2-up to 1-up when the screen is small, you'll have to specify a media query size and bump up each column to 12 when in that size
4. You can also try FlexBox